# Xml attendance: output attendance of selected student c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having a little trouble.  This is what my xml look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Students xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="student.xsd">
<Student>
<StudentID>001</StudentID>
<FirstN>John</FirstN>
<LastN>Doe</LastN>
<Seat>A1</Seat>
<PresentOn>10/7/2013 8:55:52 AM</PresentOn>
<PresentOn>10/7/2013 8:55:52 AM</PresentOn>
<PresentOn>10/7/2013 8:55:52 AM</PresentOn>
</Student>
<Student>
<StudentID>001</StudentID>
<FirstN>Jane</FirstN>
<LastN>Doe</LastN>
<Seat>A2</Seat>
<PresentOn>10/7/2013 8:55:52 AM</PresentOn>
<PresentOn>10/7/2013 8:55:52 AM</PresentOn>
<PresentOn>10/7/2013 8:55:52 AM</PresentOn>
</Student>
</Students>
```

I'm having no problem going to the specific student, say Jane Doe, but when I try to output the PresentOn dates, only the first one shows up on the richtextbox.  I've set the PresentOn element on my .xsd to be able to occur multiple times if that's any help.

How would I go about outputting all her PresentOn dates and not just one, I'm using XmlNodelist the foreach(XmlNode node in XmlNodelist) and to find the student and I'm able to output the first date, but have no idea how to output PresentOn more than once.

Here's the code I'm using to find the student:

```
XmlDocument students = new XmlDocument();
        students.Load(@"C:\SeatingChart\StudentCopy.xml");
        XmlNodeList studentID = students.SelectNodes("Students/Student");
        //user chooses student id from combobox
        string stuID = removeTextBoxSpace(comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem));

        foreach (XmlNode node in studentID)
        {
            try
            {
                string xmlID = node["StudentID"].InnerText.ToString();

                if (stuID.Equals(xmlID))
                {
                    //Messagebox showing the students name to verify correct student

                      string preson = node["PresentOn"].InnerText.ToString();
                      richTextBox1.AppendText("Present on: " + preson.ToString() + "\n");
                }
```

That's all I have so far, new at this and still so much to learn.

Comment: Show the code you use to "go to the student node", and the code you wrote to output PresentOn.

Comment: Would not the PresentOn have to be in there own node:

`<Attendance>
<PresentOn>10/7/2013 8:55:52 AM</PresentOn>
<PresentOn>10/7/2013 8:55:52 AM</PresentOn>
<PresentOn>10/7/2013 8:55:52 AM</PresentOn>
</Attendance>`

Comment: Just added the code.  Yeah I had that at first, but I couldn't find a way to create a new PresentOn node inside the Atttendance node.